# ¿Cómo puedo sacar una foto y guardarla en una carpeta del proyecto?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy usando Xamarin.forms, C#, VS 2022 en Windows, Android. Es simple lo que quiero hacer, igual como dice el titulo, busco sacar una foto, y que la foto se guarde en una carpeta dentro del proyecto. Lo que hago ya correctectmanete es guardar la imagen en una carpeta pero dentro del móvil que estoy utilizando.

Con este código guardo la foto tomada en mi celular.

```
            var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
            new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                    SaveToAlbum = true
            });
```

También opté por guardarlo en una carpeta compartida pero sin éxito. Hay errores en conexión al servidor.

Esto es como intento guardarlo en el servidor.

```
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);
            if(status == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (photo != null)
                {
                    ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                    {
                        var stream = photo.GetStream();
                        photo.Dispose();
                        return stream;
                    });

                    //Convert ImatgeStream to BYTE[]
                    var imageToByte = ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(photo);
                    //var photoName = photo.AlbumPath.Substring(20, photo.AlbumPath.Length);
                    var windowsAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("dominio", "ususario", "contraseña");
                    string path = @"\\ip\carpeta" + photo.AlbumPath;
                    path =  path.Replace("/", @"\");

                    var dest = new SmbFile(path, windowsAuth);
                    
                    dest.CreateNewFile();
                    var writeStream = dest.GetOutputStream();
                    writeStream.Write(imageToByte);
                    writeStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Estoy utilizando SharpCifs.Smb, Pero todo lo que intento me tira el siguiente error:

> SharpCifs.Smb.SmbException: Failed to connect

Y bueno decidí optar por otro camino, que es la de guardar las imagenes en una carpeta lamada "Fotos" dentro del proyecto, y de ahi pasarlas al servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]